# undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code in my Rails view:

```
-if program.description.length > 214
          -total = 0
          -perfect_index = 0
          -program.description.split(' ').each do |word, index|
            -total += word.length
            -if total >= 214
              -perfect_index = index - 1
              -break
          =program.description.split(' ')[0..perfect_index].join(' ')
          \...
-else
  =program.description
```

I don't know why index could have the value of `nil:NilClass`. I feel like the issue is with my `haml` scoping of variables, which probably isn't working as I think it should, but I don't know how to ameliorate that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

calling just `each`, not `each_with_index` causes the problem

should be `program.description.split(' ').each_with_index do |word, index|`

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use index than you have to use `each_with_index`

```
program.description.split(' ').each_with_index do |word, index|
```